# prime number python for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, prime-factoring

**Question:**

A program that take a positive integer n as input and returns True if n is a prime number, otherwise returns False.

**My Answer:**

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        print(False)
print(True)
```

when I enter a prime number it works but when I enter a non prime number it doesn't work.

**Example:**

```
>>> 
Enter a number: 12
False
False
False
False
True
>>>
```

please help!

Comment: Do you mean doesn't work for the non prime?

Comment: you are not returning anything ... (and tbh you only need to check up to sqrt(n))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `break` and use `else`:

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        print(False)
        break
else: 
    print(True)
```

`True` will only be printed if the loop completes fully i.e no  `n % i` was equal to 0.

Comment: @JafarOcean, no worries, if you are not using a function this is probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

Your code *always* prints `True` at the end, and prints a number of `False`s before that.  Instead, you should have a variable (`isPrime`?) that gets initialized to `True` and gets set to `False` when you find it is divisible by something.  Then print that variable at the end.

Comment: so how would it look?

Answer (score 1):

You're just printing each intermediate value, if you use `return` in a function it works fine

```
def prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True

>>> prime(5)
True
>>> prime(12)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the for-else clause here. Also, you don't need to go beyond the square root of `n`:

```
import math

for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
    if n % i == 0:
        print "False"
        break
else:
    print "True"
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of different ways to fix your code, but all of them hinge on the fact that you should be breaking out of that loop if you find a divisor (ie if `n%i == 0`)

Usually, you'd have a boolean value storing whether or not you've found a divisor, but python lets you do the following

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        print(False)
        break
else:
    #else statement only happens if you don't break out of the loop
    print(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an `i` which gives modulo zero with `n`, then you have to print `False` and then do nothing. For this you can use a `flag` variable which takes care of this condition. If no such `i` is encountered, flag remains `1` and `True` is printed.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number: "))
flag = 1
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        print(False)
        flag = 0
        break
if flag:
    print(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the algorithm here:

http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number

```
# Python program to check if the input number is prime or not

# take input from the user
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))

# prime numbers are greater than 1
if num > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           print(num,"is not a prime number")
           print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
           break
   else:
       print(num,"is a prime number")

# if input number is less than
# or equal to 1, it is not prime
else:
   print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one, it should make clear why the `else` statement is indented 'non conventionally':

```
num = int(input('Enter the maximum value: '))

for number in range(3, num+1):
    #not_prime = False
    for factor in range(2, number):

        if number%factor == 0:
            #not_prime = True
            break
    #if not_prime:
        #continue
    else:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the above things are correct but I want to add thing that you should check for the condition of 1. if someone puts 1 as an integer you will have to return False. 1 is not prime

Answer (score 0):

```
def prime_num(num):
    if num <= 0:
        return "the number is not primary"
    for i in range(2, num - 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return "The number is not primary, it can be divided: " + str(i)
    return "The number: " + str(num) + " is primary"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many ways to solve it:

```
def is_prime(num):
if (num == 2):
    return True
elif any(x for x in range(2, num - 1) if (num % x == 0)):
    return False
else:
    return True
```